# 'signIn' was called on null. problem google signIn Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, google-signin

I use Cubit in my app, and i want to login with Google.
I write codes which are in below, but it gives error: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'signIn' was called on null.

How can i solve this? Where is the problem?

```
Widget googleSignInButton() {
  return BlocBuilder<GoogleSignInCubit, GoogleSignInState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: OutlinedButton.icon(
        label: Text(
          'Sign In With Google',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
        ),
        icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.google, color: Colors.red),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<GoogleSignInCubit>(context).signInWithGoogle();
        },
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

.
final gSignIn = await googleSignIn.signIn(); >>>>>  I think the problem is here..

```
class GoogleSignInCubit extends Cubit<GoogleSignInState> {
  GoogleSignIn googleSignIn;
  bool isSignIn = false;

  GoogleSignInCubit() : super(GoogleSignInState.initial());

  Future signInWithGoogle() async {
    final gSignIn = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    if (gSignIn == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      final googleAuth = await gSignIn.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
      final existingUserDocs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: gSignIn.id)
          .get();

      if (existingUserDocs.docs.isEmpty) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).set({
          'email': gSignIn.email,
          'username': gSignIn.displayName,
          'uid': uid,
          'userPhotoUrl': gSignIn.photoUrl
        });
      }
      isSignIn = true;
      emit(GoogleSignInState.success(isSignIn));
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

.

```
abstract class GoogleSignInState with _$GoogleSignInState {

  const factory GoogleSignInState({@required bool isSignIn}) = _GoogleSignInState;


  factory GoogleSignInState.initial() => GoogleSignInState(isSignIn: false);



  factory GoogleSignInState.failure(String failureMsg) = _Failure;
  factory GoogleSignInState.success(bool isSuccess) = _Success;
}
```

Comment: i also use freezed, but i think it does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the google sign in.
You can initialize like this:

```
GoogleSignInCubit({@required this.googleSignIn}) :
 super(GoogleSignInState.initial());
```

Of course you will have to pass the google sign in when you create the cubit.

```
BlocProvider<GoogleSignInCubit>(
   create: (context) {
      return GoogleSignInCubit(googleSignIn: GoogleSignIn(
         scopes: [
            'email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
         ],
      ),
   }
)
```

Another way to initialize (which is what I would prefer in this situation) is to make the googleSignIn variable private by changing it to _googleSignIn. Then:

```
class GoogleSignInCubit extends Cubit<GoogleSignInState> {
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
  bool isSignIn = false;

  GoogleSignInCubit({GoogleSignIn googleSignIn}) :
  _googleSignIn = googleSignIn ?? GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
     ],
   ), super(GoogleSignInState.initial());

  Future signInWithGoogle() async {
```

Comment: type 'GoogleSignInCubit' is not a subtype of type 'GoogleSignIn'
it gives this error

Comment: also i used the code which is below in 'You forgot' line
it worked, but i do not understand the other codes. 
For example, you mention that 'I PREFER', both it did not work and i did not understand, can u expain

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the issue. First one should have worked though.